# How do I force mosh to try connecting again?

Tags: ssh, mosh

I've not had this problem before. Typically when my system comes back from sleep, mosh is perfectly happy.

However, I have a mosh session open right now that says "mosh: Last contact HH:MM:SS ago"

When I open a separate mosh session to the same server it tells me that I have a detached mosh session. So clearly the session is still there on the server. And it's still here on the client. But for some reason the client won't actually connect. I can establish new connections just fine - and I even have other sessions to other servers that are working just fine.

So, how do I force mosh to actually try and reconnect or am I just out of luck?

Comment: try sending the escape character and suspending the session (ctrl-z) and then putting it in the foreground again.